# Strip symbols from static library in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I have the following scenario:
An application I'm working on includes a library let's call it static library 1.
Static library 1 includes (among other functionality I must have) Google analytics , Facebook and Flurry in old versions.
In that app I intend to use a SDK I'm developing which also uses Google analytics , facebook and flurry.

Theoretically - I have no problems compiling a slim version of my SDK that will take those implementation from the static library 1 - Assuming we both use the same version of facebook and flurry. (Iv'e done so in the past and it works)

But since the library is old the version of the facebook and flurry sdks is older and I cannot use it.
Is there anyway to strip those symbols or to override them? I don't mind putting all the libraries at the project level or any other solution of that type.

Thanks in advance,

Liviu

Comment: On Mac OS X, see if the `strip` or `nmedit` commands will do what you need. Open `Terminal` and enter `man strip` or `man nmedit` to read the documentation.

Comment: @NedNowotny .. I don't think that's what he wants.. he says 'symbols' but he want to remove the whole functions. Unfortunatly you can't remove a static linked library from another library without recompiling it... and you can't link a two libraries with the same function names but different versions.

Comment: It depends... If the symbols can be removed or hidden in a static library, the linker will not complain about duplicate functions across libraries. Then, most linkers for C long ago were able to copy out only the code used from a static library when building an executable. Of course, not all linkers ignore unused code in a static library and there is no guarantee that a static library compiled with one version of code will actually work when linked with another version. For one thing, changes in header files will not be picked up by code compiled against a different version.

Comment: Rebuilding from source is the only reliable solution here. However, mucking with the static libraries might work if rebuilding from source is not possible. Unlikely, but it might work...

Comment: I'll have to try the stripping , though I guess I'm in for a very long manual process that will not even surely work. time for a 1 symbol POC eh? :) (I was told they are not using those libs in that project , but I remain a bit skeptic).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this one? Looks quite easy...

http://atnan.com/blog/2012/01/12/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-errors-during-linking-by-removing-classes-from-static-libraries

Comment: This must be a comment.

Comment: Just explaining why this is not entirely the solution - Symbol stripping will enable me to keep the internal works of the library the same , while removing it and using the newer ones might cause issues with that library inner works.